# Bevel object flipping unexpectedly

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, bevel

[image: Text]
Above is the issue I am having.
I would like to edit the path as below:
[image: Text]
In the second gif, I can use the move tool to taper and bend the hair. This is what I would like to do.

In the first gif, however, the bevel object begins to turn and flip after a certain y value.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to get an answer on this question anywhere. The closest workaround I've found is to just A -> ctrl+T and flip the curve before starting. Ended up working reasonably well.